# Can annotations generated using wsimport be overridden?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a problem where I receive the following web service exception, using client code based on `wsimport` generated classes:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: 
@Action and @WebMethod(action="" does not match on operation opName
```

I believe the problem is due to the generated port type source having `@WebMethod` with a value (i.e. `@WebMethod(action = "http://www.test.net.au)`), when really it should be simply `@WebMethod`.

The only real reason this seems to have occurred is that the WSDL defining the SOAP operation has changed from:

```
<wsoap12:operation soapActionRequired="false" style="document" />
```

to

```
<wsoap12:operation soapAction="http://www.test.net.au" style="document" />
```

Is it possible to force the `@WebMethod` annotation to have no value, assuming that will solve my problem?

Comment: So it turns out the inclusion of the soapAction attribute violated a conformance point on the SOAP 1.2 specification I was working from. The solution was to add back the soapActionRequired="false" attribute. That's not really an answer to the question so please feel free to provide an answer if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes were required to the WSDL. Reverting to the original `soapActionRequired="false"` example in my above question.